# Bidirectional DShot not working after 5 beeps (BLHeli_32)

Tags: betaflight, dshot, bidirectional-dshot

I have a 4in1 ESC (Mamba 45A 96k) with BLHeli_32, my FC is running Betaflight 4.3.
Since the last crash one ESC only works with normal unidirectional DShot. As soon as I enable bidirectional DShot, I get 100% error rate from that ESC, while all the others work fine.

All 4 Motors beep 5 times, which means that the ESC recognizes the signal and the connection is fine. But it does not spin and it does not return any RPM data. Hovering works without bidirectional DShot.

I tried lowering the update frequency, but it did not change. Lowering the baud rate to DShot 300 also does not help.

Comment: Wild guess: something with the return path broke off. Try swapping pads around on the FC and see if it follows

Comment: @BrydonGibson yes, that seems to have been the issue. Using another ESC didn't change anything, but using the other motor header on the FC did the trick (it's an octocopter FC, but I'm only using 4 motors)